# Python script to renew key from Vault every 30s

Tags: python, multithreading

A small Python lib to renew key from Vault every 30s to always get the latest key.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import hvac
import time
import threading
import os


VAULT_URL = os.environ['VAULT_ADDR']
VAULT_TOKEN = os.environ['VAULT_TOKEN']


class Client:
    def __init__(self, *keys):
        self.keys = keys
        self.data_dict = {}
        self.client = hvac.Client(
            url=VAULT_URL,
            token=VAULT_TOKEN)

        self.__renew()

    def read(self):
        for key in self.keys:
            self.data_dict[key] = self.client.read(key)
        return self.data_dict

    def __renew(self):
        self.client.renew_token()
        threading.Timer(30, self.__renew).start()
        self.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client('secret/key')
    print(client.read())
```

Comment: What kind of output does this generate? A steady stream of new keys, a onetime output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the need for threading here, as it seems like it only generates a one-time key. If this was some kind of long-time running process it would make a little more sense, but I still believe I would rather use a method which kept track of the last request, and if that request was made more than 30 seconds ago then read a new key from the `hvac.Client`.

The following code is totally untested:

```
import hvac
import time
import threading
import os
import datetime

VAULT_URL = os.environ['VAULT_ADDR']
VAULT_TOKEN = os.environ['VAULT_TOKEN']

class Client:
    def __init__(self, *keys):
        self.keys = keys
        self.data_dict = {}
        self.client = hvac.Client(
            url=VAULT_URL,
            token=VAULT_TOKEN)

        self.read_keys()


    def read_keys(self):
        self.client.renew_token()

        for key in self.keys:
            self.data_dict[key] = self.client.read(key)

        self.last_read = datetime.now()


    def read(self):

        # If more than 30s since last read, renew keys
        if (datetime.now() - self.last_read).total_seconds() > 30:
            self.read_keys()

        # Return the secret keys
        return self.data_dict
```

Hopefully, not too many errors in there, but it should the gist of the idea, if I understood your underlying requirements of getting new keys every 30s or so correctly.

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit more why threading is not needed?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a class here. Neither you need a `Timer`.

```
import hvac
import time
import threading
import os
import sys


VAULT_URL, VAULT_TOKEN = sys.argv[1:]


def read(client, *keys):
    client.renew_token()
    return {k: client.read(key) for key in keys}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = hvac.Client(url=VAULT_URL, token=VAULT_TOKEN)
    while True:
        print(read(client, 'secret/key'))
        time.sleep(30)
```